# jupyter runs an old pytorch version

Tags: python, conda, jupyter-lab

I have elementary knowledge on package managers, so forgive me if my question is phrased badly.

I am using miniconda as a package manager. I have python 3.8 installed, and I use jupyter lab to run ipython kernels.
My issue is that when import `torch` then the version 1.7.1 is loaded to the notebook, however, when I look at `conda list` I see that version 1.8.1 of torch is installed.

When I try to update using `conda update --all` and `conda update pytorch` nothing is being installed.

So

1. I don't know why pytorch is not updated to the new version of 1.9.
2. I don't know why an older version 1.7.1 is loaded to my jupyter notebook.

would love to get some help!

Comment: An educated guess: your jupyter kernel is in a different environment and contains the old copy of pytorch.

Comment: I am not using environments really (at least not intentionally). When I run `print(sys.executable)` I get `/Users/user/opt/miniconda3/bin/python`. but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what solved it, but:
I updated homebrew which required me to install some command line tools of x-code, and then I managed to install pytorch again using
`conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch`.

Now the proper version is loaded when I use jupyter.